# Play multiple sound files in sequence only playing last sound

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

This app plays a sound based on a number. I have multiple audio files which are very short mp3's. as the question says, I want it to play all sounds in sequence, one after the other but only the last sound (number) is playing and I get the error on the console saying:

"Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a new load request."

I'm missing something or maybe this is not possible to do. Any help is appreciated.

```
function playSound(note){

    var currentPlayer;
    var player = document.getElementById("player");

    var isPlaying = player.currentTime > 0 && !player.paused && !player.ended 
&& player.readyState > 2;


     if (!isPlaying){

        player.src = "sounds/"+note+".mp3";
        player.play();

     }else{
        player.pause();
        player.currentTime = 0;
        currentPlayer = player;

     }



}


//variable with numbers where each number should load a sound and play
var numString = "0934590042529689108538569377239609480456034083552";


for(i = 0; i < numString.length; i++){


    switch (parseInt(numString[i])){
        case 1:
            playSound("C"); 
            break;
        case 2:
            playSound("D");
            break;
        case 3:
            playSound("E");
            break;
        case 4:
            playSound("F");
            break;
        case 5:
            playSound("G");
            break;

        case 6:
            playSound("A");
            break;

        case 7:
            playSound("B");
            break;

        case 8:
            playSound("C2");
            break;

        case 9:
            playSound("D2");
            break;


        case 0:
            playSound("silence");
            break;


}
```

The Html:

```
<audio controls id="player" style="display: none">
    <source  src="#"></source>
</audio>
```

Comment: That loop completes in milliseconds. It doesn't wait for each sound to complete before setting the next `src`. You would need a recursive function that uses end of one sound to set the next

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wait for the first note to finish before loading the next one:

```js
var index = 0;
var numString = "0934590042529689108538569377239609480456034083552";
var notes = ['silence', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'B', 'C2', 'D2'];
var player = document.getElementById('player');

function playNote() {
  if (index >= numString.length) {
    stop();
    return;
  }
  var note = notes[Number(numString[index])]; // transform the number to the corresponding note ('1' => 'C')
  if (!note) {
    stop();
    return;
  }
  index++; // when 'playNote' is called the next time, the next note will be played
  player.src = `sounds/${note}.mp3`;
  player.play(); // when this ends, the 'ended' event will be fired and 'playNote' will be called
}

function stop () {
  player.removeEventListener('ended', playNote); // the last note has been played, remove the event listener
}

player.addEventListener('ended', playNote); // whenever the sound ends, call 'playNote'
playNote(); // start to play the first note
```

### Edit:

I changed the `this` to `player` in the `playNote` function. When this function is called for the first time (`playNote()`), there is no `this` object refering to the `player`. It should have been `playNote.call(player)`. But as it is right now, it should as well.

To reduce the load times between the notes, you have two possibilities:

#### Load the sound files separately in more than one `audio`s

For each note, create a `new Audio()` and load the sound file:

```js
var numString = "0934590042529689108538569377239609480456034083552";
var notes = ['silence', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'B', 'C2', 'D2'];
var audios = {};
notes.forEach(note => {
  var audio = new Audio();
  audio.src = `sounds/${note}.mp3`; // load the sound file
  audios[note] = audio;
});

var currentAudio = null; // the audio that is currently playing

function playNote () {
  if (currentAudio) {
    currentAudio.removeEventListener('ended', playNote); // remove the event listener from the audio that has just stopped playing
  }
  if (index >= numString.length) {
    return;
  }
  var note = notes[Number(numString[index])]; // transform the number to the corresponding note ('1' => 'C')
  if (!note) {
    return;
  }
  currentAudio = audios[note];
  index++; // when 'playNote' is called the next time, the next note will be played
  currentAudio.play(); // when this ends, the 'ended' event will be fired and 'playNote' will be called
  currentAudio.addEventListener('ended', playNote);
}

playNote();
```

#### Use the `AudioContext` API

The new [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) is much more complex than a simple `new Audio()`, but much more powerful. You don't need to have every possible sound file on your server - you can use the client's sound chip to create whatever sounds you want.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I tried your code, and I'm getting the error          "Uncaught TypeError: this.play is not a function"

Comment: Alright I changed "this"  for "player" and it works. Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Is it possible to make it load quicker? or play faster?